# RFM69W and LoraWan

Tags: lora, arduino, lorawan

I'm trying to figure out how I will make an RFM69W LoRa Module work with The Things Network, so I looked over many tutorials, code samples, and libraries. The one I find closest to LoRaWan support is:

https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic because of LoRaWan support.

But it seems that has a specific chipset support that may not be compatible with adafruit RFM69W.

The one that mentioned in adafruit's site is just sending bulk data over an rf channel such as [radiohead](https://github.com/adafruit/RadioHead) and [powerlab's](https://github.com/LowPowerLab/RFM69) after a quick look over the libraries for arduino.

Has anyone tried to use the chip with LoRaWan specs, if yes then how did you do it, which libraries did you use for arduino?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify from what I undestand when researching these modules:

- RFM**69**x - Packet Radio (**not LoRa**)
- RFM**96**x - LoRa Radio (or RFM95 / RFM97 - thanks [Chris](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/737/chris-stratton))

If you're trying to use an RF69x for LoRa, that's your issue

A quick google search should show you how to get LoRaWan up and running if you have the correct radio module (RFM9xx).

Hope this helps.

([Link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-rfm69hcw-and-rfm96-rfm95-rfm98-lora-packet-padio-breakouts/overview) to adafruit learn page for the radio modules I believe you are referring to)

Comment: You are correct that the RFM69 is not a LoRa device, however the RFM96 is not the only LoRa capable module in that series, and the **RFM96 is not the one you would typically want, as it supports only the lower bands**, while The Things Network is primarily on 868 or 915 MHz (by region).  For this you want the RFM95 or possibly 97

Comment: Good point, I was previously looking at a project for 433MHz so that slipped my mind! Will edit to include this